# How to exit a main sub within a called sub

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 subs that look like this:
How can i stop my "main" sub if my statement is true in the sub i just called?

```
Public Sub main()
    call run()
    more code....
End Sub

Public Sub run()
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        (i want to stop the code running if this statement is true, it shall not continue in my main sub.)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Return` will exit from `Run` convert it to a function to return a value whether to end the app or not.  it is not clear whether you want to abort one or both.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: use the statement Return

Comment: I would like to abort both. Is there a simple way to do that?

But if i return to Sub main() it will continue running below my call run() line. I would like to stop before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it if `Run()` is a Sub. You need your `Run()` as a Function. return a Boolean indicating if you want to stop `main`, and call in inside an `If`:

```
Public Function run() As Boolean
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Return True
    End If
    ' some more code if needed
    Return False
End Function
```

Then call it in your main sub like this:

```
Public Sub main()
' some main code here
    If Run() Then
        Return
    End If
' The rest of main code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)